# PHP shell input sanitizing

Tags: php, git, shell, security

I want input of alphanumeric string (sha1 - git commit ID). Is sanitizing with regexp `/[^a-z0-9]/`, using `preg_replace` with blank string enough to safely pass it to shell?

Comment: well, usually `escapeshellarg()` is the best way... http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: This looks intresting, I didn't know about this... Thanks

Comment: It really pays out to invest some time to look into the php documentation. It will save you a lot of time in the end if you get an overview about what exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. You can use `[^0-9a-f]` instead of `[^0-9a-z]` to prevent someone from passing a non-hexadecimal character.

```
$arg = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-f]/', '', $arg);
if (strlen($arg) === 40) {
    // We have a SHA-1 hash
    shell_exec("git checkout {$arg}");
}
```

In general cases, [`escapeshellarg()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) is what you want to use, but narrowing it down further for your specific use-case is a good idea as well.